# Debug SVG drawn using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, google-chrome-devtools

I am using javascrpit to draw some svg graph. Is there a way that I can debug towards the svg graph produced? Specifically, I am looking for something like the element inspector or something like that, that can point me to the code that draws that part of the svg graphics.

Comment: You can see the generated code in the inspector.

Comment: Also, in the Javascript debugger, can type `svg.html()`, and the html code representation of the svg up to that point will be dumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a [DOM breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom) on the SVG node? Use a **Subtree Modification** or **Attribute Modification** breakpoint. When your JS modifies the node, DevTools pauses on the line of code that caused the modification.